# Fast row operations with python sparse matrices

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix in python, and would like to perform many elementary row operations on it. That is, adding a multiple of one row to another row. What is the most efficient way of doing this? Elementary row operations are possible with a lil matrix, but very slow. csc and csr matrices do not support these operations.

Comment: AFAIK, each time you add a non-zero entry to an existing sparse matrix, the whole matrix needs to be copied (array elements are stored in order, and this order needs to be amended with a new entry; also the memory needed to encode the matrix changes). Addition will always be slow for sparse matrices. If the matrix is too large to load into memory, I would suggest working on a dense matrix saved on the hard disk in an indexable format such as hdf5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a MCVexample would help the question a lot.  I can only speculate about your row operations.

A fundamental question - do the rows differ in their sparsity structure?  Take the `lil` case.  If 2 rows have the same `rows` lists, then your math can work with the `data` lists directly.  If `rows` differ than math becomes much more complicated, since you have to change both lists.

Both `lil` and `csr` support indexing by row

```
In [7]: M=sparse.rand(10,10,.3)
In [8]: Mr=M.tocsr()
In [9]: Ml=M.tolil()
```

Yes, `csr` gives a warning if you change a row by adding another:

```
In [17]: Ml[2,:] += Ml[1,:]
In [18]: Mr[2,:] += Mr[1,:]
...
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

But the `lil` math actually uses a `csr` intermediary.  `lil` rows are represented as lists, not arrays.

```
In [14]: Ml[1,:]+Ml[2,:]
Out[14]: 
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Indexed matrix operations are slow, especially compared to the dense array equivalents.  But they take care of a lot of little details for you.

I've explored row operations in other SO answers.  When I have a better idea of what you are trying to do, I search those.

Overall, there isn't a magic bullet, especially if you are changing sparsity.  `scipy sparse` isn't the best tool for fast row calculations.

[scipy: Adding a sparse vector to a specific row of a sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231040/scipy-adding-a-sparse-vector-to-a-specific-row-of-a-sparse-matrix) - this one is close enough that I'm tempted to flag this question as a duplicate.

[Extremely slow sum row operation in Sparse LIL matrix in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231458/extremely-slow-sum-row-operation-in-sparse-lil-matrix-in-python)

(more in a SO search on `'user:901925 [scipy] rows'`)

Comment: Unfortunately, two rows of my matrix will generally not have the same sparsity structure. Thank you for referring me to the other links. I didn't know about them.

Comment: For me, (the poster) this solution worked: Express the matrix as a 2-level nested dictionary where row i, column j is accessed through d[i][j]. Adding two rows is then 'adding' d[i1] to d[i2], which is discussed  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe).