# K Nearest Neighbors (KNN) for sparse matrices using custom distance metric

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, nearest-neighbor

Given a sparse matrix (created using [`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html)) of size NxN (N = 900,000), I'm trying to find, for every row in testset, top k nearest neighbors (sparse row vectors from the input matrix) using a custom distance metric. Basically, each row of the input matrix represents an item and for each item (row) in testset, I need to find it's knn.

Attempts:

- Tried using [`sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors). However, it appears that sklearn doesn't take callable metric function as input when dealing with sparse matrices:

  ```
  ValueError: metric '<function <lambda> at 0x7f92ce221938>' not valid for sparse input
  ```
- Currently trying to use [facebookresearch/pysparnn](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pysparnn) (looks really promising!). It has a certain provision for implementing one's own custom distance class. However, after execution, it's taking quite long to build the index (still running after 24 hrs) and as [mentioned](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pysparnn/issues/11#issuecomment-285901090) by the author, it seems that

  > using distance types from `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` (or sklearn distance metrics) is much slower than what is currently in pysparnn.

  We're in process of debugging this performance issue of sklearn/scipy distance metrics by writing something custom.

I'd like to know if there is any other efficient implementation of nearest neighbor search for sparse matrices which provides for using a custom distance metric?
(Will be executed on a server with 64 GB RAM, 12 cores)

Thanks!

Comment: What does an NxN matrix represent?  It might help if you demonstrated this with, say a 10x10 dense array.

Comment: @hpaulj question's metadata re-framed once again. Let me know if any additional information is required and if demonstration using a dense array is still needed for clarification.

Comment: Do you need exact nearest neighbours or would an approximation do?

Comment: @ali_m exact nearest neighbors would be preferred since the accuracy might get affected at later stages. However, I'm open for alternatives using approximations too.

Comment: I just talked about comparing sparse rows here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/42905909/901925

Comment: When you compare two sparse rows, will you use the intersection of nonzero values, or their union?  In other words is the comparison more like multiplication, or more like addition/subtraction?

Comment: @hpaulj while comparing two sparse rows, I'll be having arithmetic operations on their overlapping non-zero values (intersection).
For instance, the distance metric to be used is [np.minimum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) over the data of two sparse vectors and then getting sum of the resultant array (= custom distance value). I hope I'm able to clarify the intent.

Comment: @ali_m any headers on the approximate nearest neighbors approach?

Comment: @hpaulj would you like to have any further inputs for a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: I think this might be useful: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9199